# Remove black margin from elementaryOS applications when using Awesome Window Manager

Tags: applications, window-manager

I bought an Alpha Centurion laptop that comes with a pre-installed elementaryOS, I'm using awesome window manager (https://awesomewm.org/) and when I start elementaryOS "native" apps (like io.elementary.calculator, scratch-text-editor, ...) I get an ugly, big, black margin around the app.

This is the calculator over a browser window
[image]

Any way to remove/reduce the black margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a custom theme?
try this http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/fix-large-black-borders-around-header.html

Comment: I'm unsure if the pre-packaged OS has any customization to the theme, nevertheless your solution worked perfectly.