# GTK 3.22 migration of older gtk.css -> Black Margin on elementaryOS apps

Tags: gtk, xorg

I have a legacy gtk.css that was working fine on Ubuntu Xenial, I've just upgraded to Bionic (2018) and the same code now is not working anymore:

```
$ cat .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css 
.window-frame {
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

this code was needed to remove an ugly black border from windows as explained here [Remove black margin from elementaryOS applications when using Awesome Window Manager](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14548/remove-black-margin-from-elementaryos-applications-when-using-awesome-window-man).

I tried the selector `.frame>border` in the debugger `$ GTK_DEBUG=interactive io.elementary.calculator` but to no avail.

Anyone that follows GTK devel and knows how to update the CSS code? I tried to look into the official docs but couldn't find anything related to .window-frame having changed.

Answer (score 1):

The `.window-frame` tweak does not work anymore on recent versions of GTK3 due to massive CSS overhaul. Here is a patch that seems to effectively disable these black borders on GTK3 (tested on [version `3.24.18-1` of `gtk3`](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/releases/tag/3.24.18)), to be written in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
window > decoration {
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This kind of solution can be derived using the [GTK Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector) to debug GTK apps displaying issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `.window-frame` got changed in GTK CSS 3.22 from 3.18. For the sake of Google I coulnd't find into what got changed (someone mentioned `frame` but that doesn't work).

So I got a brutal patch that seems to kind of work and have few side effects:

```
* {
   box-shadow: none;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

[image: GTK3.22 remove black border]

hope this helps others while a proper solution is discovered.